# Probability and Measure Theory by Ash

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

Has anyone used the textbook above? If so how does it compare with billingsley, Chung and similar such books in terms of rigor, coverage, and ease if use for self study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Ash to self-study some more advanced probability theory on my own. I've found the experience to be fairly decent, and it covers most of what I'm looking to learn (basic probability, conditional probability, martingales, limit theorems, and ergodic theory). I have not looked through Chung, but I find it is more or less similar to Billingsley and Durrett. The Ash book has fairly detailed answers to select exercises in the book. Billingsley has that too, although they are not as detailed IMO.

Comment: What was your background when you started to self-study from this book? How much weekly time did you dedicate to study from this book? How long did it take you overall? I'm asking because I'm doing it right now and it is fairly difficult to advance (my rate is something like 1 page in 3 days or so)